# How to properly scale a glyph of an SVG font using an SVG symbol viewBox

Tags: svg, fonts

I'm utilizing the Bravura music font.

Here's its font-face definition:

```
<font-face 
    font-family="Bravura"
    font-weight="400"
    font-stretch="normal"
    units-per-em="2048"
    panose-1="5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
    ascent="1638"
    descent="-410"
    bbox="-889 -4080 4749 4120"
    underline-thickness="102"
    underline-position="-102"
    unicode-range="U+0020-1D1DD"
  />
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around font metrics.  I've studied the explanation on [this site](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html): But I'm still unclear.

My goal is to translate the glyphs into a properly scaled SVG path using an SVG symbol [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute.

So the EM square (which is an imaginary square enclosing each glyph) is 2048x2048 units (defined by units-per-em).  A unit is 1/72 of an inch.  My monitor DPI is 96x96

Converting this to pixels = `2048 * 96/72` = `2730 1/3 x 2730 1/3`

(Let me know if I'm off here)

So each font should natively fit into a `2730 1/3 x 2730 1/3` square?

How does the bounding box #s fit into this process?  Are the bbox units in glyph-units as well? (`1/72 in`)

Should the bbox value below be directly inputted into the viewBox attribute of a symbol?

Do I need to consider ascent and descent values?

Here is a jsfiddle somewhat demonstrating my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/1wqa384u/5/

Any resources or help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The em box encompasses the ascent and decent.  Notice that `ascent-descent=2048`.

As for your main question, I think you are confusing yourself a bit.  The viewBox tells the browser how to scale the symbol to fit the size specified by the `<use>` that references it.

So if I understand what you want correctly, your symbol viewBox should just be `"0 0 2048 2048"`.

You should then be able to draw it at, say 12pt, by referencing it like so:

```
<use xlink:href="#mysymbol" x="100" y="100" width="12pt" height="12pt"/>
```

You shouldn't have to worry about doing your own DPI conversion.

Comment: Ahh this helps a lot.  Almost there.  Using a viewBox of 0 0 2048 2048 cuts the top half of it off.  I'll see if I can do a jsfiddle for you.   Give me a moment, thanks!

Comment: Yes sorry. I made a mistake.  The viewBox will actually be something more like `"<leftsidebearing> (<em>-<ascent>) <em> <em>"`.  Depending on what transform you use to correct the Y coordinate inversion.  Your clef symbol definitely goes outside of the 2048 though.  It's viewBox seems to be something like `"0 -2255 2605 3605"`.

Comment: I should have mentioned there is a `horiz-adv-x='1024'`
So after some fiddling + your advice - the viewbox formula seems to be:

0 (0 - em - descent) (em + horiz-adv) em

Comment: This also implies the width/height ratio should be `.75`.
Also `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"` is needed.

Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/1wqa384u/8/

Let me know if this seems right and I'll mark you answer : )

Comment: If your `<use>` width and height has the same aspect ratio as the symbol viewBox, then the `preservAspectRatio` value shouldn't matter.  However you seem to have a wide viewBox and a narrow use width.

Comment: Hmm.  With `preserveAspectRatio` set to `none`, the only way I could get this to display properly is by doubling the max x / max y and ensuring the aspect ratio was 1:1 - http://jsfiddle.net/1wqa384u/9/

I feel like I'm just shooting guesses out here now.  I need to figure out a way to understand the conversion process here.

Comment: So the font-face definition you provided in your question is the one for the font that the clef is from?  If so, then the issues you/we are having are because the clef glyph extends outside the em box.  So you will get issues with clipping when you try to scale based on a viewBox derived from the em box.  What you should just do then is use a viewBox of "0 0 2048 2048" and in your `<use>` set width and height to 80pt. Finally set your `<symbol>` to have `overflow="visible"`. See http://jsfiddle.net/1wqa384u/11/  And just do the same thing for all your glyphs.

Comment: Yes exactly.  Oh wow, this totally makes sense now.  I wasn't aware of the overflow attribute, thanks for pointing it out.  But now that I think about it - the "G Clef" as this symbol is called - is suppose to be horizontally aligned exactly where your two red dots are (the baseline).  Given that, it appears obvious that this font was meant to have overflow.  I think this points me in the exact direction I need to go.  Perhaps I'll contact the font creator to try to extract more info.  Thanks for your patience and help `BigBadaboom`, much appreciated!